# How to Connect automatically with client from server

Tags: c#

In c# programming, I want to connect with client from server

Still I wrote the program of a client/server application. After getting response from both sides then connection will be established. But I want to just single click from server side connection to have established. I don't know how to go.

Comment: Now are you talking about a database server? If so, what type?

Answer (score 3):

Ashish, in client server programming, the initiation of a connection is usually a client side task. You may want to read up more on Client Server Programming here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-server

Answer (score 0):

You should start by clarifying what the difference between your "client" and "server" is.